Why is the h264parse plugin not categorized as 'good'?
I'm currently using GStreamer in my project, specifically the h264parse and the tsdemux plugin. I've noticed that this plugin is not categorized as 'good', and I'm wondering if there is a specific reason for this classification.
Could you provide some insights or point me to the appropriate resources?
I've checked the official documentation and release notes, but I didn't find any relevant information.
My project depends on this plugin, so I would appreciate any help or guidelines about its stability and potential issues.

What is it categorized as instead? Where do you see this?

Back when I was a kid, Bad was goooood.

https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad says "gst-plugins-bad: a set of plug-ins that aren't up to par compared to the
rest.  They might be close to being good quality, but they're missing
something - be it a good code review, some documentation, a set of tests,
a real live maintainer, or some actual wide use."

(Tank you for comment.)
categorize : gst-plugins-bad
h264parse
tsdemux
source--
gsth264parse,c
tsdemux.c
